# How to get the response until the server complete?

Tags: java, android

Here is the Server class within the server connection. I need to get the response and  check the result after the server process complete. The following codes only check the result before got the respond.

```
public class Server {
    
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
        public void httpPost(String URL) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(URL);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        connection.connect();
                        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
    
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                stringBuilder.append(line);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               
                    server.httpPost("https://google.com?username=Peter");
                    if (server.stringBuilder.toString().contains("Successful")){
                         Log.d("test",server.stringBuilder.toString());
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your server call is asynchronous, it runs on a separate thread, so `httpPost` returns immediately before the call is finished. This is a really common question, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/70178210#70178210) for some possible solutions. You need to use a callback to wait to run the validation code until after the response is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you don't use retrofit library? Retrofit easy way to work with api's.**

[You can find here retrofit library](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

**Retrofit has two callback:**

```
call.enqueue(callback) - asynchronous, runs the request on a background thread, and runs the callback on the current thread

call.execute() - synchronous, runs the request on the current thread.
```

**I use call.enqueue(callback). Because this is asynchronous and this callback does not freeze ui components.**

Answer (score -1):

You need learn REST API libraries volley, retrofit or ktor.
You can use any library.

Volley: https://google.github.io/volley/

Retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Ktor: https://ktor.io/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).